# Update a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

> I'm a newbie in programming bit i was able, looking to code sample to
>   male some small scripts that write a new CSV starting from a list of
>   stringa andò a web api. Now I have a problemi : I have a CSV, "|"
>   separate values and there are about 30 cols. I need to tale forma each
>   row it s value andò male an operation Mike value of the cell  is its
>   originale vale /100... I need to write the result on the sane file. I
>   know that is noto possibile direct use of the file. i know that a way
>   could ne pur data in a list and at the end update tge sane file but i
>   m not abile to make a simple script. Soneone van help me?

*Edited - best guess at a translation*

I'm a newbie in programming but i was able, looking to code sample, to make some small scripts that write a new CSV starting from a list of strings and a web api.

Now I have a problem: I have a CSV file, with "|" separated values and there are about 30 cols. I need to take from each row its value and make an operation with the value of the cell equal to is its original value / 100.

I need to write the result on the same file.
I know that is not possible direct use of the file.
I know that a way could  data in a list and at the end update the same file but I'm not able to make a simple script.

Can someone help me?

Comment: This is hard to follow, care to edit it to make it easier to understand what's going on?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively update any existing file "in-place" by first giving it a temporary file name and then writing a new file with its original name.

```
import csv
import os

filename = 'mytestfile.csv'
tempfilename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.bak'
try:
    os.remove(tempfilename)  # delete any existing temp file
except OSError:
    pass
os.rename(filename, tempfilename)

with open(filename, mode='wb') as outfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='|')
    with open(tempfilename, mode='rb') as infile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|')
        csvwriter.writerow(next(csvreader))  # copy header
        for row in csvreader:  # update column in each row
            row[1] = float(row) / 100  # update column in each row of data
            csvwriter.writerow(row)

os.remove(tempfilename)
```

Comment: for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|'):
            row[1] = 42  # update column of row
            csvwriter.writerow(row)

Comment: for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|'):
            row[1] = 42  # update column of row
            csvwriter.writerow(row)

Comment: Sorry. this means a statica valute 42. how to pur in the value of 'old' column 1 /100 forma each row

Comment: See update of how to do that. Also note that you may have to just copy the first row if your csv file starts with a header row.

Comment: yes I made a count and if check to copy the header of the CSV.